# Regex: A metacharacter to recognize any type of character

Tags: regex, kotlin

I want to be able to recognize the following pattern:
`$...$`

with `"..."` being any type of character.

How can it be done in Kotlin?

Comment: Do you mind restoring your original question and then posting your current question as a new question? I could update my answer to reflect your new question but then others with a similar question as your original question would not be able to find the question/answer.

Comment: Done. returned the original question.

Answer (score 3):

The dollar sign (`$`) is a boundary matcher for the end of a line so you have to escape it with backslash (`\`). Kotlin has two types of strings: escaped and raw (see [Basic Types - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)). If you use escaped strings then you'll need to escape the backslash with a backslash. Below are various ways to declare your desired `Regex`:

```
"""\$.{3}\$""".toRegex()
"""\$...\$""".toRegex()
"\\$.{3}\\$".toRegex()
"\\$...\\$".toRegex()
Regex("""\$.{3}\$""")
Regex("""\$...\$""")
Regex("\\$.{3}\\$")
Regex("\\$...\\$")
```